# react-native-sensors orientation yaw wrong values

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, sensors

Trying to get gyroscope values on android physical device. Portrait mode . Using react-native-sensors library and orientation object. Need yaw and pitch values. Seems that they are somehow dependent between each other. Yaw should work as level instrument

My code:
in init:

```
const subscription = orientation.subscribe(onPhoneLevel);
setSubscriptionPhoneLevel(subscription);

const onPhoneLevel = (orientation) => {
  
        try {
            let yaw = orientation.yaw * 180 / Math.PI;
            let roll = orientation.roll * 180 / Math.PI;
            let pitch = orientation.pitch * 180 / Math.PI;

            if(screenOrientation === "PORTRAIT") {
                yaw -= 90;
            }
            setAngleYawVisual(parseFloat(yaw.toFixed(1)));
            setAnglePitchVisual(parseFloat(pitch.toFixed(1)));
            setAngleRollVisual(parseFloat(roll.toFixed(1)))
        }catch (e) {
            ControllerLogging.logError(e);
        }
 }
```

Everything is working fine when my phone lies on the table. If I grab it, all values start to change randomly.

any suggestions? I may predict there are needed complicated math formulas, but ... found nothing that is working.